# Azure Active directory integration c# windows application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

[image: Screenshot for Flow]  We need to integrate the Azure Active directory with the our Add-in project for Login implementation single sign on mode.

So, in this case how can we get logged in user’s email address?

As shown in below screenshot, we are unable to fetch user email address if it is on Azure Active Directory. 
If Active directory is on local server, we are able to fetch the email address. Using following code snippet 
( System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress )

[image]

we have already tried using graph API. Although /me not working. we are getting exception as Request_ResourceNotFound

Comment: Can you add the screenshot? Also, you probably are doing authentication wrong if /me returns not found. You need to make the user authenticate against AAD by using MSAL / ADAL libraries.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVRl3.png  - URL for the screenshot in which we shown the exception. Also we are new to MSAL and ADAL. could you suggest what would be better for our use case. Our use case is show in the "Screenshot for Flow" link.

Comment: You need to use other overloads of AcquireTokenAsync, ones which log in the user. Right now you are doing client credential authentication, which is app-only and does not involve a user. This is a flow that should not be used from a Windows app like this since the secret will be available to any of the app's users. That is the reason the /me endpoint does not work, there is no logged in user.

Comment: ok. i understood. but we want to use client credential authentication only as we do not have username and password (UserCredential) of the user for single sign on. we only need to logged in user's email address to validate.

Comment: juunas it would be helpful if you can share the link of /me endpoint with workable overloads of AquireTokenSync

Comment: You can see a sample here: https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget/blob/master/DirectorySearcherLib/DirectorySearcher.cs#L40

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call Graph API with the SDK in C# application, please refer to the following steps:

1. Install SDK

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Graph
Install-Package Microsoft.Graph.Auth -IncludePrerelease
```

2. Code

```
    IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(clientId)
        .WithTenantId(tenantID)
        .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .Build();

    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) and the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS).

**Update**

If we use client credential authentication, please use the following code to get one user

```
var user = await graphClient.User
        .Request()
        .Filter("mail eq \'<your emial>\'")
        .GetAsync();
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim, i have just used and tried the same snippet and package references in my dummy console application. although its not working and not returning any output in var user. please suggest. (Used VS 19 and imported both packages) as my VS 13 was not supporting for these packages.

Comment: Hi. I am sorry. I have made a mistake. If we use client credential authentication to call graph API, we cannot use ```/me``` endpoint, we need to use ```/user/{id }```. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp.

Comment: exactly my point. but how to retrieve the **{id}** from system

Comment: Ok. Since you have the email, you can filter the user by the email.  The Url is like ```https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq '<email >'```.

Comment: no i meat id means email address here. we dont have the email. Hence looking for some other way out to get email. if its on local network we can fetch the email address from code **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress** . but as we have active directory on azure we are not able to get email address. please suggest.

Comment: @TempMailMs Could you tell me if you know something of the user? If you don't know anything, we have no way to get the user with client credential authentication. We just can use```/users``` to get the user list of your directory.

Comment: we used to get the email address of the user from this code snippet **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress**  although for user's whose active directory is on azure. we could not able to fetch the email address from above code snippet.. is it due to some access policy or is there any other way to get the user's email address?

Comment: According to my research, the code ```System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress``` can be used to get the email address of the user on-premise AD(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: If you use client credential authentication, we need to know some information of the user when we use graph api to get the user. Besides, could you tell me why you use  client credential authentication? if you have successfully integrated Azure AD with your application, only the users in the Azure AD can login your app. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa